# Why is Nifi Docker Container causing PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR when using HTTPS?

Tags: docker, firefox, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi

I've been using a docker-compose.yml file to set up a basic/simple instance of Nifi. Last week my nifi instance was working perfectly fine. Haven't changed anything to my nifi docker-compose file.

I have updated both the browser and docker desktop on Monday, and ever since then. However, my coworker has tried running the docker compose file and has had the same issue.

When I run docker compose up on the docker-compose.yml file, there are no issue in the container logs, and it seems the docker container is running perfectly fine. When I try and access 'https://localhost:8443/nifi' firefox returns the following message:

> An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8443. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

I've tried different browsers, both chrome and edge return the following message:

> This site can’t be reached localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.

I've also tried restarting my computer, docker desktop, and even the containers but nothing solved this issue. Here is my docker-compose.yml file contents:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nifi:
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN # low port bindings
    image: apache/nifi
    container_name: nifi
    ports:
      - "8080:8080/tcp" # HTTP interface
      - "8443:8443/tcp" # HTTPS interface
      - "514:514/tcp" # Syslog
      - "514:514/udp" # Syslog
      - "2055:2055/udp" # NetFlow
    environment:
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=admin
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=password1234
    volumes:
      - ../../nifi/drivers:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/drivers
      - ../../nifi/certs:/opt/certs
      - ./output:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/ls-target
      - nifi-conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
    restart: unless-stopped

 nifi-registry:
    image: apache/nifi-registry
    container_name: nifi-registry
    ports:
      - "18080:18080/tcp"   # HTTP interface
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Not sure what my next steps should be. I have followed the instructions on this site "https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/pr-end-of-file-error/" but no luck. I feel as if it must be something with docker desktop or the container that's causing an issue with certs on the browser. Since, both my coworker and I are having this issue.

Answer (score -2):

That error is normal. It should go away after a few minutes. Basically, it is trying to unzip those NAR files in the background.

It is normal for Apache NiFi to take some time to start up, especially when using a Docker container. The startup process involves unzipping the NAR (NiFi Archive) files for each processor, which can take a significant amount of time, depending on the number of processors and the performance of your system.

The NAR files are archives containing the necessary code, resources, and metadata for each processor. Unzipping these files is an essential step during the NiFi startup process, as it makes the processors available for use in your data flows.

Although the unzipping process can be time-consuming, it should not cause issues in most use cases. Once NiFi has started and all processors are loaded, you should not experience any additional delays due to the NAR unzipping process.

If you find that the startup time is causing issues in your development or production environment, you can consider the following options:

Optimize your Docker container: Ensure that your container has sufficient resources (CPU, memory, and disk space) to run NiFi efficiently. You can also try to optimize the Docker settings for better performance.

Reduce the number of processors: If you have a large number of custom processors that you don't need, consider removing them from your NiFi installation. This will reduce the number of NAR files that need to be unzipped during startup.

Use a custom NiFi build: If you are using a large number of custom processors, you can create a custom NiFi build that includes only the processors you need. This will reduce the number of NAR files and potentially speed up the startup process.

Keep in mind that NiFi's startup time should not affect its performance during runtime. Once the application is up and running, you should be able to create and manage data flows without any issues related to the NAR unzipping process.

Comment: Using ChatGPT to post answers is forbidden. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned